# Mistake in LMFDB integral points in elliptic curve $y^2+y=x^3-3x+4$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, elliptic-curves, integers

According to LMFDB the integral points of the [elliptic curve](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/135/a/1) $$y^2+y=x^3-3x+4$$ are $(−2,1)$, $ \left(-1, 2\right) $, $ \left(1, 1\right) $, $ \left(2, 2\right) $, $ \left(4, 7\right) $, $ \left(13, 46\right) $, $ \left(19, 82\right)$.

But I found that: $(x,y)=(-2,-2),(-1,-3),(1,-2),(2,-3),(4,-8),(13,-47),(19,-83)$ are also solutions, but they are not listed. Why is that?

---

[image]

Comment: They spell it out right there. **Note: only one of each pair $\pm P$ is listed.** Do you know how to get $-P$ if you know $P$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I do not exactly know what they mean by that statement, so no I do not know how to get that. I'm not a native English speaker

Comment: This is not about English. Do you know what the group operation on an elliptic curve looks like?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No, that is something I do not know.

Comment: That is explained in an early chapter on every book about elliptic curves. Or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve)? What source are you studying ECs from?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You mean that all the other solutions I found can be found using the group operation of EC?

Comment: More precisely: they are the negatives of the listed ones. In Weierstrass form $P$ and $-P$ share the $x$-coordinate. To a given $x$ the equation has at most two solutions for $y$. If one solution is an integer so is the other, because the equation is monic and has integer coefficients.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that is weird because $(-1,-1)$ isn't a solution and for example $(19,-83)$ is also not listed in the exsisting list.

Comment: Nothing weird about it. If $P=(1,1)$, then $-P=(1,-2)$. Did you read the comment where I describe how to find $-P$ when $P$ is known? They are the two points sharing the same $x$-coordinate.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh yes sure I see. But what about $(19,-83)$?

Comment: If $P=(19,82)$ then $-P=(19,-83)$. Mind you, LMFDB overwhelms me too. I have only studied elliptic curves for less than year after getting my PhD, so I only know the basics. LMFDB is designed to be more useful to people who seriously study elliptic curves :-)

Answer (score 2):

This could not be a comment, so it is an answer... The short answer is:

https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/135/a/1

explains that only one of $\pm P$ is shown.

*Long answer:*
I am trying to explain the reason by using [sage](https://www.sagemath.org). Here, if we ask for the integral points...

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve(QQ, [0, 0, 1, -3, 4])
sage: E
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 - 3*x + 4 over Rational Field
sage: E.integral_points() 
[(-2 : 1 : 1),
 (-1 : 2 : 1),
 (1 : 1 : 1),
 (2 : 2 : 1),
 (4 : 7 : 1),
 (13 : 46 : 1),
 (19 : 82 : 1)]
```

we get the above list of seven points. Since most people most times ask for the integral points on a curve given by the simpler equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, and in this case we obviously see the points coming in pairs $(x,\pm y)$, there is a default implicit decision in the computation to show only "the half" of the points. To see them all, we need to explicitly ask for

```
sage: E.integral_points(both_signs=True)
[(-2 : -2 : 1),
 (-2 : 1 : 1),
 (-1 : -3 : 1),
 (-1 : 2 : 1),
 (1 : -2 : 1),
 (1 : 1 : 1),
 (2 : -3 : 1),
 (2 : 2 : 1),
 (4 : -8 : 1),
 (4 : 7 : 1),
 (13 : -47 : 1),
 (13 : 46 : 1),
 (19 : -83 : 1),
 (19 : 82 : 1)]
```

and we get more. In this case, for a specified value of $x$, say $x=x_0=19$ we know, that the equation in $y$
$$
y^2+y = (19^3-3\cdot 19+4)
$$
has an integer solution, the other one is (Vieta) making their sum equal to $-1$.

There is often a reason to "compute / show only half of the points", databases need half space, computation algorithms may make a choice...

And indeed, let us ask sage to show the pairs of points $P, -P$ in the same line:

```
sage: for P in E.integral_points():
....:     Q = -P 
....:     print( "P = %8s and -P = %8s" % (P.xy(), Q.xy()) )
....:     
....:                         
P =  (-2, 1) and -P = (-2, -2)
P =  (-1, 2) and -P = (-1, -3)
P =   (1, 1) and -P =  (1, -2)
P =   (2, 2) and -P =  (2, -3)
P =   (4, 7) and -P =  (4, -8)
P = (13, 46) and -P = (13, -47)
P = (19, 82) and -P = (19, -83)
sage:
```

Comment: Are the results proven? Are those the only solutions that exists? If yes can I find that anywhere?

Comment: @JanEerland The documentation of the method can be obtained in the sage interpreter via `E.integral_points?` . It also exists as a link: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_rational_field.html and citing it... " 

*Note

This function uses the algorithm given in [Coh2007I].* " (Sorry, i saw the comment today first...)